# HTML mail image

Tags: html, image, email

I am wirting email in html code and i dont know how to put image in there. Do I need to use absolute link from server or is there any other way.

Should it be like this? `<img src="something.com/image.jpg" alt="hello" />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Email images must link to a url where the image is hosted.

```
<img src="http://www.yourdomain.com/image.jpg" alt="hello" />
```

You can also just use an image hosting site like [flickr.com](http://www.flickr.com/).

```
<img src="http://www.flickr.com/photos/your_photo_id.jpg" alt="hello" />
```